# Vector container and static binding in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, virtual-functions, static-binding

Can someone please explain why `i->value()` and `(i + 1)->value()` prints 1 and 3 not 1 and 4 like  `x[0]->value() << x[1]->value()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0) : m_n(n) { }

public:
    virtual int value() const { return m_n; }
    virtual ~A() { }

protected:
    int m_n;
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    B(int n = 0) : A(n) { }

public:
    virtual int value() const { return m_n + 1; }
};

int main()
{
    const A a(1); //a.m_n=1
    const B b(3); //b.m_n=3
    const A *x[2] = { &a, &b };
    typedef std::vector<A> V;
    V y;
    y.push_back(a);
    y.push_back(b);
    V::const_iterator i = y.begin();

    std::cout << x[0]->value() << x[1]->value()
              << i->value() << (i + 1)->value() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup says, if you know *victor*, you also know C++. They're bestest friends and they always roam around together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`y.push_back(b);` creates an instance of `A` which is a copy of the `A` subobject in `b`, and pushes that onto the vector. There are no instances of `B` on the vector, nor could there be, so `B::value()` is not called. Read about [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: In contrast, no slicing happens when creating `x`, because `x` holds pointers or references (in this case pointers) to objects of class `A`.

Answer (score 3):

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

will create an `A` copy of `val` if the vector is defined as `std::vector<A> V`.
You see here so called [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).
This is why you should use

```
std::vector<A*> V
```

or

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<A> > V
```